# serialize form to json and store in the cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization, cookies

i want to store form on clientside, in json in cookie, after that deserialize it back to form.
what i'm doing:

serialization to JSON:

```
function formToJSON(selector) {
    var form = {};
    $(selector).find(':input[name]:enabled').each(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var name = self.attr('name');

        if (name.indexOf('TextBox', 0) == 0) {
            if (form[name]) {
                form[name] = form[name] + ',' + self.val();
            }
            else {
                form[name] = self.val();
            }
        }
    });

    return form;
}
```

then on form change, i'm trying to save form to cookie:

```
 $('#form1 :input').change(function () {

    var eba = formToJSON($('#form1'));

    $.cookie.set('fo', eba, {json:true});
    var a = $.cookie.get('fo',true);
    alert(a);


    //$.cookie.set('form123', { "ksf": "saf", "tt": "" }, { json: true });
    //var b = $.cookie.get('form123', true);
    //alert(JSON.stringify(b));
});
```

in debugger - eba is json object, but alert(a) gives null.
commented code works, this json serialized, and i'm gettin it from cookies.
but why code doesnt work for form???
cookie plugin taken from jquery.com

Comment: Two probs I see immediately: first selector should not have ':' at the start, and you can skip the `[name]` bit too. Second, when you call `formToJSON` you need only pass a string, though this latter one isn't going to cause a problem (it's just inefficient).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this library to stringify/parse JSON http://json.org/js.html

remember that there is an approx 4KB size limit on cookies , http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306070

Comment: do not understand what for i need to use it.

Comment: Sorry, I would always use this library to serialise and de-serialise between JSON and JavaScript objects. It is faster and more robust than anything I could write in a reasonable amount of time. At least this way I know I only need to worry about the storage pare. I used this with the HTML5 localStorage with no problems. You still need to pull the element from the form and put it into an object for store. Cookies only really store strings, have you stepped through the cookie plug in code to see what gets stored?

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK browser cookies cannot be read using javascript(except for your own domain), to prevent [Cross Site Reeuqest Forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)
But you can still set them.

Comment: @wildcard : my bad, i forgot to mention the fact:).